# How i can create sharepoint navigation more than three level in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, menu, sharepoint-2013, submenu

I use `SharePoint 2013`

How i can create sharepoint navigation more than `three level` in SharePoint 2013 ?

Somethings like this :

```
Site Navigation -> Test 1 -> Test 1.1
                -> Test 1 -> Test 1.2

                -> Test2 -> Test 2.1
                -> Test2 -> Test 2.2 -> Test 2.2.1 -> Test 2.2.1.1
                                     -> Test 2.2.1 -> Test 2.2.1.2
                                     -> Test 2.2.1 -> Test 2.2.1.3
                -> Test2 -> Test 2.2 -> Test 2.2.2
```

I use

```
 `Site Setting` -> `Look And Feel` -> `Navigation` 
  -> Open the `Term Store Management Tool` to edit term sets.
```

And I create navigation like this :

[image]

But My result is like this :

[image]

Why `Test 2.2.1.X` Do not show ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cumulative updates installed? The issue with dynamic navigation subnodes has been fixed in the last cumulative update, namely August 2013 CU.

Be sure to install the public update first:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2767999

Then get the appropriate update package suiting your license:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/08/14/august-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx

Comment: I download public update ubersrvsp2013-kb2767999-fullfile-x64-glb.exe from first link and install it in share point. and then i download all package because i do not know my share point version. but any of package can not be install and show a window that say this package is not match with your share point version. my server is 64 bit i download all package 64 bit.have you any idea?

Comment: Loup, can you put "/_vti_pvt/service.cnf" (as in http://mydomain/_vti_pvt/service.cnf) into your browser and post here what version is displayed? Once you get that you can check the version reference here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx#Build

Comment: Hi. After use this  KSCOLAP/_vti_pvt/service.cnf  , I get two line : 'vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl'
'vti_extenderversion:SR|15.0.0.4420' And in second link not exist any package for my version?!? how can i do?

Comment: Can you try installing the October 2013 update? The Server version is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825647 and the foundation version here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825674

Comment: Oh, and please don't forget to run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard once you're done installing.